# Indicate fields can be editable on row hover in extjs 4

Tags: extjs4.2

I would like to add a border on the fields that are editable when the rows are in "hover". Any idea on how to do this in EXTJS 4?

Comment: Can someone please look into this issue?

Comment: you could use tooltip

Comment: My question is how can we determine whether a cell can be editable or not on row hover